# Merge two image into one but both image as same size in android

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have two images. One is taken by camera and another one is browsed from gallery. But are in different size. I need to merge two images to one image. But both are need to same size. I have written code to merge two image to one. But it displaying different image size. One is (taken by camera) is small. Another one (browsed from gallery) is big size. But I need both to be of same size.

My code:

```
Bitmap cs = null; 
Bitmap c= bmp;
Bitmap s = galerypic;

int width, height = 0; 

if(c.getWidth() > s.getWidth()) { 
    width = c.getWidth(); 
    height = c.getHeight() + s.getHeight(); 
} else { 
    width = s.getWidth(); 
    height = c.getHeight() + s.getHeight(); 
} 

cs = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888); 

Canvas comboImage = new Canvas(cs); 

comboImage.drawBitmap(c, 0f, 0f, null); 
comboImage.drawBitmap(s, 0f, c.getHeight(), null); 


//    String tmpImg = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".png"; 

//putStream os = null;
FileOutputStream outStream = null;
try { 
    outStream = new FileOutputStream(String.format("/sdcard/merged.jpg"));   
    // os = new FileOutputStream(loc + tmpImg); 
    cs.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outStream); 
} catch(IOException e) { 
    Log.e("combineImages", "problem combining images", e); 
}
```

Comment: Manage the image size according to the aspect ration, on the basis of the small image from the two and resize the large one.

Comment: Please don't forget to accept the working answer, as requested. To do so, click on the tick mark to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you set the width and height for both images to be the same as the wider one of the two, then you can calculate the width and height of the target image like this:

```
int width, height = 0; 

if(c.getWidth() > s.getWidth()) { 
     width = c.getWidth(); 
     height = c.getHeight() * 2; 
} else { 
     width = s.getWidth(); 
     height = s.getHeight() * 2; 
} 

cs = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888); 
Canvas comboImage = new Canvas(cs);
```

Then use the version of [DrawBitmap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap,%20android.graphics.Rect,%20android.graphics.Rect,%20android.graphics.Paint)) that accepts a source and destination Rect, specifying a destination rectangle to scale them into. You can specify null for the source Rect (second parameter) to draw the entire bitmap:

```
Rect dest1 = new Rect(0, 0, width, height / 2); // left,top,right,bottom    
comboImage.drawBitmap(c, null, dest1, null);
Rect dest2 = new Rect(0, height / 2, width, height); // left,top,right,bottom    
comboImage.drawBitmap(s, null, dest2, null);
```

Comment: I am really thanx to you. i struggled this step.But no  one give any idea.At the correct time you save my. Thanx  lot.Its working fine